# Timestamp of yesterday at specific hour bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I need to schedule a query on BigQuery, that will retrieve some data from 24h ago. The problem is that for example if its scheduled for 5am, the query needs time to be executed (let's say 2.248 seconds), and so the yesterday's data from 5:00:00.000 to 5:00:02.248 will not be retrieved. I'm using a timestamp field, and i do something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 24 hour)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the yesterday's date, at a specific hour, so even if there is a little gap due to the execution, it will still retrieve data from a specific hour.

edit:
I found something :

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_timestamp >=  TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
AND my_timestamp < TIMESTAMP(current_date)
```

But this retrieves yesterday between 00:00:00.000 to 23:59:59.999

It is okay but is there a way to choose the hour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below least verbose approach

```
select *
from my_table
where my_timestamp >=  timestamp(current_date - 1 + interval 5 hour)
and my_timestamp < timestamp(current_date + interval 5 hour)
```

Comment: Thx it is better like this indeed

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found on my own lol, maybe it will help someone else looking for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_timestamp >=  TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
AND my_timestamp < TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(current_date), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```